# How to bind Image source?

Tags: wpf, image, binding

From some examples, I think I'm doing this right, but it's not working so I wanted to check here to see. I'm binding my Image source, but the image is not there. If I take away my binding and just set the Image source to the path used in the method below it works fine.

```
public Image myImage = new Image();

public void someMethod() {
    BitmapImage biSource = new BitmapImage();
    biSource.BeginInit();
    biSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    biSource.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
    biSource.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Images\testimage.jpg");
    biSource.DecodePixelWidth = 150;
    biSource.EndInit();

    myImage.Source = biSource;
}

xaml code
<Image Source="{Binding Path=myImage}" Width="150" Height="150" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should bind the `Source` property to an `ImageSource`, not an `Image`. Expose `biSource` as a property and bind to it instead of `myImage`

Comment: Ts, i was half a minute faster :(

Comment: @H.B., sorry, didn't notice your answer... here's +1 to make up for it ;)

Comment: Haha, thanks, it's not like it's your fault anyway, simultaneous answers happen a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You try to bind an `Image` to the source of an `Image`, not going to work. You need to bind the `BitmapImage` to the source of the `Image`.

Also the `BitmapImage` needs to be exposed as public property. If you are new to data binding read [this overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Further you should learn [how to debug bindings](http://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20debug%20wpf%20bindings&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a).

Comment: I read through the overview and looked into debugging bindings. Thanks for the direction.